# Validate remote server certificate using thumbprint / fingerprint while using requests library in python

Tags: python, python-requests, x509certificate

Greeting, I am a novice in python and trying to send a request to the internal server which is using a self-signed certificate. I am using `requests` library to do this.
currently for temporary purpose I used it as :

```
requests.post(url=remote_url, json=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

As this cannot work in production I need to do the certificate validation based on the SHA1 or SHA256 thumbprint available In the certificate. (I know better to validate it by providing the certificate directly as cert=chain.pem but It is not possible for me).  Is there any way to perform the thumbprint validation while connecting to the server?

Thakns in advance!!

Comment: *cert=chain.pem but It is not possible for me* I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. The server must send the cert for every connection so it's not particularly difficult to obtain a copy. If you had a thumbprint what would you be hashing to compare to the thumprint?

Comment: we are taking thumbprint as a input from USER. While connecting to the remote server we will get the sha1 and sha256. Which will be validated against user input.